# Applying CSS in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, hover

I need help in applying CSS to my Javascript. As I am not good at this, I just want to ask all of you who know. Anyway, I use JS in my hover of menu. Below is the code:

```
$(function(){
     $('a img').hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('_off', '_on'));
          }, function(){
             if (!$(this).hasClass('currentPage')) {
             $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('_on', '_off'));
        }
   });
});
```

In my HTML, it looks like this:

```
<tr>
<td valign="top"><a href="#"><img src="img/tabs_01_off.png" width="229" alt="tabs_01"/></a></td>
<td valign="top"><a href="#"><img src="img/tabs_02_off.png" width="229" alt="tabs_02"/></a></td>
<td valign="top"><a href="#"><img src="img/tabs_03_off.png" width="229" alt="tabs_03"/></a></td>
<td valign="top"><a href="#"><img src="img/tabs_04_off.png" width="229" alt="tabs_04"/></a></td>
</tr>
```

The hover works for all the tabs, but I wanted the tabs 1 and 4 when hovered, just covers the content behind. It should not move the contents going down, but that's what happens right now actually. I was advised to use `position:relative` and `z-index: -1` because when using overflow, it may not work in IE6. So please help, thanks!

Comment: Sorry I don't have the time to write a proper answer. You can make it pure CSS, without using JavaScript. Also consider if you really need support for IE6. I favorite it for later review if no one answered your question.

Comment: $(this).css('position', 'relative', 'z-index', '1');

I used that but the CSS does not work.

Comment: That's not the right way to use `.css`. It should be `$(this).css({'position': 'relative', 'z-index': '1'});`

Comment: Hi jlansner! Thanks for the help. I edited the JS but the hover isn't working anymore when I added that line. why? I used -1 in my z-index.

Comment: Hi. Does z-index work in position:relative? 'Cause I changed it to absolute then it's working but the menu disappears when I hover.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to add a class

```
$(this).addClass("myClass");
```

If you really want to use the .css syntax you need one call per style change like this:

```
  $(this).css('position','fixed');
  $(this).css('z-index','1');
```

Here is a jsfiddle of your code with a guess of what css you want to change. jsfiddle.net/G4BgT Please provide more information about what you want to happen.

Comment: Hi. I actually added this but it doesn't work.

$(this).css('position', 'relative', 'z-index', '1');

And I'm confused with your advice.

Comment: Lets start with this and maybe you can describe in better detail what you want to happen. http://jsfiddle.net/G4BgT/

Comment: @MonicaNegapatan: This is not the correct way to use `.css`. Please read the documentation first before you use a new method: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2.

Comment: Hi. Does z-index work in position:relative? 'Cause I changed it to absolute then it's working but the menu disappears when I hover.

Comment: When you set position: relative on an element then you establish a new containing block. All positioning inside that block is with respect to it.

Setting z-index on an element inside that block will only alter its layer with respect to other elements inside the same block.

If you set all elements up the DOM to position:relative it will create a new containing block for each and then the z-index's are applied correctly.